# How to tell if Spring's InterceptingClientHttpRequest is processing an HTTPS request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to intercept `RestTemplate` HTTP requests.

How can I determine if a given `HttpRequest` is an HTTPS request?

I noticed that implementation class of the `HttpRequest` is [`InterceptingClientHttpRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE_to_4.3.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/client/InterceptingClientHttpRequest.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
httpRequest.getURI().getScheme().contains("https")
```